# Angular 1.5 "track by" ruines binding in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to select option in combobox from ajax loaded data. That data comes as list of objects. The problem is that ng-option compares objects by reference and thus setting model to objects element results in appearing new empty option in combobox instead of selecting correct option.

The known workaround is to use `track by` expression.
And here is example code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.roles =[
    { key:"administrator", value:"ROLE_ADMIN" },
    { key:"operator", value:"ROLE_OPERATOR" }, 
  ];

  // this emulates data from server
  // won't work without 'track by'
  $scope.role={ key:"administrator", value:"ROLE_ADMIN" };

});
```

Template:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
0: <input ng-model="roles[0].key" />
<br>
1: <input ng-model="roles[1].key" />

<br>
  select role: <select ng-model="role" ng-options="r.key for r in roles track by r.value">
  </select>

  <pre>selected role={{role|json}}</pre>
</body>
```

Here another problem arises. When one selects role in combobox and then
changes it's "key" property in textbox, then selected role stays unchanged. So it looks like binding is suddenly gets broken.

https://jsfiddle.net/xLqackxw/8/

Comment: It will work if you change the ngOptions to `<select ng-model="role" ng-options="r.key for r in roles ">`, why do you need to `tack by`?

Comment: @AlonEitan He needs `track by` because his API probably returns several objects with same `value`.

Comment: @AlonEitan, updated question and added code comment to clear up this.

Comment: @Dfr - The `role` model is a copy of the selected role, it's not referencing to the actual `$scope.roles` - If you add `{{ roles | json }}` to the view, you'll see that the roles array is changing correctly

Answer (score 0):

from Angular documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

So:

```
<select ng-model="role" ng-options="r as r.key for r in roles track by r.value"></select>
```

'$scope.role' value will be object like { key:"administrator", value:"ROLE_ADMIN" } or { key:"operator", value:"ROLE_OPERATOR" }